# How to Implement ITestListener in Cucumber+Selenium+Java

Tags: selenium, cucumber, testng, cucumber-java

I've created a project where am trying to run Cucumber+Selenium+Java tests using TestNG plugin.
My Runner class is :

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources", monochrome = true, glue = "com.ipkgs.stepdefinitions", plugin = {
        "html:target/cucumber-html-report", "json:target/cucumber-json-report.json" }, dryRun = false)
public class CucumberTests extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }

}
```

I am creating a listener class where I want to get the result details as well as the scenario details like at which scenario failed at which step.

I am extending ItestListener but it is only giving me the pass/fail result without scenario details.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**You shouldn't use TestNG listeners for that.** While Cucumber "knows" about TestNG, TestNG in turn does not know anything about Cucumber. You need to use [hooks mechanism](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#hooks) for watching your scenario execution status.

**Example from documentation:**

```java
@After
public void doSomethingAfter(Scenario scenario){
    // Do something after after scenario
}

@AfterStep
public void doSomethingAfterStep(Scenario scenario){
    // Do something after after step
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried that earlier but problem is that I need to implement these hooks in each step def file

Comment: What do you mean? According to the docs *Where a hook is defined has no impact on what scenarios or steps it is run for*. What are you trying to achieve? Can you share the use case?

Comment: The hooks can be defined only in the step definition files. isn't it? So I have to place the hooks in each of stepdef file?

Comment: No it isn't. There is no such a term as "step definition file" (at least if you're talking about classic syntax where you define your steps with annotations). Step definition is not a class but a method. So nothing stops you from keeping your hooks at a separate class. It has to be places at the package or sub-packages of what you specify in `glue` option.